# How to hide link when user has already selected action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a wink system that when clicked on "I'm interested" it will send the user a message. How can I setup so that if a user clicks on "I'm interested" from a the status that it will send a message to that user automatically. I want to add a way so that when the "I'm interested" link is clicked for that status, it then becomes unavailable to that users. This is to prevent the user from sending 30 messages from the same status message which would result into being spam. The text can remain there but the link should be removed from the text if user has already use that action from the status.

Intrigued controller:

```
def interested
  @intrigue = User.find(params[:id])
  @intrigue = current_user
  @recipient = Intrigue.find(params[:id])

  @message = Message.create(:subject => "Someone is Interested in you",
                         :sender_id => @intrigue.id,
                         :recipient_id => @recipient.user_id,
                         :body => "I saw your date and I'm interested")
    render :new, alert: 'Your message was sent.'
end
```

View:

```
<% if current_user?(intrigue.user) %>
                <%= link_to "delete", intrigue, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }%> <% end %> <% unless current_user?(intrigue.user) %> | <%= link_to "repost", repost_intrigue_path(intrigue), method: :post %> | <%= link_to "Interested", interested_intrigue_path(intrigue), method: :message %>

                        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need some methodology to look up if a `Message` exists with the `current_user` as the `sender` and the `recipient` as the page the user is on.  Something like this:

```
<% if current_user.has_sent_message?(@user) %>
  Text only
<% else %>
  <%= link_to ... %>
<% end %>
```

`has_sent_message?` would be an instance method on `User`, like:

```
def has_sent_message?(user)
  Message.find_by_recipient_id_and_sender_id(user.id, self.id).present?
end
```

Comment: The "wink" system uses the inbox messaging system. So there could be messages established between the sender and recipient already. So it wouldn't be practical to do that unfortunately.